# How to detect HTML hidden Attribute with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working in the analytics field and most of the time I'm using CSS selector to solve my issue. Right now I'm working on a website were I need to detect if a `<p>` element is hidden or not. so here is the two possible situation :

```
<p namehere hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
<p namehere This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
```

What's the most simple way to return a boolean regarding the hidden status of the `<p>` element ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the quickest and simplest way to achieve this is the following

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p:not([hidden])');
```

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

You could catch all the `p` elements with `getElementsByTagName` function, iterate over them and check if specified element has `hidden` attribute different than `null`.

Note: If `hidden` attribute is null - element has no hidden attribute.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    Array.from(elems).forEach(function(v,i) {
      if (v.getAttribute('hidden') == null) {
        console.log(v);
      }
    });
```

```html
<p namehere hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
<p namehere>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `getAttribute`.  In this case, `getAttribute` would return `null` if there's no attribute or `''` if there was one.

You can iterate over tags like so:

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
  if(paragraphs[i].getAttribute("hidden") !== null){
    // The paragraph is hidden and can be accessed with paragraphs[i]
    console.log(paragraphs[i].innerHTML + ' is hidden');
  } else {
    // The paragraph not is hidden and can be accessed with paragraphs[i]
    console.log(paragraphs[i].innerHTML + ' is not hidden');
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p hidden>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question, but... Methods described here don't seem to be

> "(...) **the most simple way to return a boolean** regarding the hidden
> status of the
>
> element (...)"

While getting all `<p>` element is necessary, using `getAttribute()` method is NOT. Instead, simply test the hidden attribute from the element object:

1. **Just returning a boolean related to the hidden attribute: ([Array.from() syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#syntax))**

```js
Array.from(
  document.getElementsByTagName("p"),
  element => console.log(element.hidden)
);
```

```html
<p namehere hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
<p namehere>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
```

2. **If you want to do an action depending on the boolean return, you should prefer this syntax:**

```js
//Using forEach() method instead of map() for better loop handling 
Array
  .from(document.getElementsByTagName('p'))
  .forEach( element => {
    if(element.hidden){
      console.log("This element is hidden.");
    }else{
      console.log("This element is not hidden");
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<p namehere hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
<p namehere>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
```

Eventually, no `getAttribute()` method, no comparison operator, **only boolean property check**. Sounds more straightforward IMHO.

Ref : [HTMLElement.hidden property (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with Jquery you can directly use hasClass function.

[Jquery hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

If you are looking for pure javascript you can use this function

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + element.className + ' ');}
```